# If $\phi = f(x,y)$ where $x=t^2, y=\sin(t^2)$, express $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ in terms of $f_{x},f_{y}$ and $t$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm very confused how to go about answering this sort of question. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just use chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule:
$$\frac{df(x(t),y(t))}{dt} = \frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial x}\frac{dx(t)}{dt} + \frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial y}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\ .$$
Note: I know the notation I used is ugly and suboptimal, but I wanted to make explicit the dependence on the variables.

Comment: Thank you that's helped clear up a lot!

Comment: @gorillaz You're welcome. I'm happy that helped.

Answer (score 2):

The multivariate chain rule yields, with your notations:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm d t}=f_x\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}+f_y\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d t}.$$